# Error after upgrading from Teradata 12 to Teradata 13....terasso.dll

Tags: odbc, teradata

We are currently upgrading our Teradata clients from v12 to v13. For that, the old installations of Teradata 12 were uninstalled from the system and TTU13 was installed.

After installation when I try to add a ODBC connection using the new Teradata driver, it gives me the following error.

> Unknown error occurred in terasso library

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: We did some more research and found that Teradata GSS is not getting installed from the installation package. The installation process is also a silent install. Please help us out on this issue. We also need a way to switch off silent install so that we could view the error on Teradata GSS install.

Comment: Can you check for any other exe file which is not a silent install?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to uninstall the Teradata GSS and the Shared ICU Libraries for Teradata 12 and the Teradata 13.x ODBC driver. Once all of those items have been uninstalled, reboot the computer, and then install the Teradata GSS and Shared ICU Libraries for Teradata 13.x before installing the Teradata 13.x ODBC driver.

Typically the install package for Teradata will prompt you for which packages are about to be installed silently and provide you the option to disable the silent install individually for whichever packages are normally installed silently.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading my Teradata tools using TTUExpress/TTUBase.exe

**ODBC drivers had also to be upgraded using TTUExpress/TTU_DBM.exe**

before that 
- SQL assistant couldn't manage to connect, giving some fuzzy messsage.
and 
- The "ODBC administrator" program was slightly more explicit with the "Unknown error occurred in terasso library" message.

Comment: had the problem upgrading from v14 to v15

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the folder: \Teradata\Teradata GSS\nt-i386**LCLIENT**

That one was missing after a silent install. I have seen this on at least one machine, only workaround was executing the EXACT same install commands from a cmd window instead of using a Powershell script.

That LCLIENT appears to be some sort of redirected thing after a default installation, that is a reason why you can't AppV this thing properly if not copying the contents, removing the "shortcut" and recreating a proper LCLIENT *folder* in the same location, copying the contents back.

Order for proper operation is 1) GSS, 2) ICU, 3) ODBC. If you don't it will error out always.