# Unknown error occurred in terasso library, unable to connect to teradata using vba

Tags: windows, vba, odbc, teradata

I have really simple code. Last line return such error, I use not english version, so it might look a bit different: "*the data source is not found and a default driver is not specified*".

```
Private objConn As New ADODB.Connection    'Connection...
Private objRS As New ADODB.Recordset    'Recordset...
Private objErr As ADODB.Error    'Errors...

Dim strSQL as String, intJobCodeRequested as Integer

'Prompt User for job code...
intJobCodeRequested = InputBox("Please enter the job code desired:  ", "Teradata Program", " ")

'Connect to database using DSL set in the ODBC setup...
objConn.Open "Driver=TeradataDSN; Server=Teradata Server Name; Database=Database Name; UID=User ID; PWD=Password"
```

So after that:

I run the 32 Bit ODBC Data Source Administrator, then
pressed "Add"
then selected "Teradata" from the list
pressed "Finish"

As a result I get an error message *Unknown error occurred in terasso library*

I`m using teradata v 14.1. OLDP driver is installed, according to registry. Teradata GSS is also installed (folder exist in Teradata folder).  And according to [this](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/tools/ttu/install/index.jsp?topic=%2FE_14_10_Windows_EclipseHelp%2FSharedICUFiles_win.html), Shared ICU Libraries are also installed.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't install everything required.  Make sure you install Teradata GSS and the Shared ICU Libraries

Comment: @Andrew nope, they are both installed

Comment: How were the drivers, GSS, and ICU libraries installed? Order has been known to be an issue in past releases.

Comment: @RobPaller How - I think  all at once remotely have been installed by some it-department. What do you mean by *Order*?

Comment: @RobPaller Is that can be a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909824/error-after-upgrading-from-teradata-12-to-teradata-13-terasso-dll ?

Comment: Re-installing the drivers as mentioned in the link you provided may solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Unknown error occurred in terasso library" occurs when the ODBC drivers still need to be upgraded, after some other teradata tools was.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44890712/1767316) to see how to upgrade your ODBC drivers.